# how to have unfocus event in kivy text Input

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am building a German dictionary app where there is an option to get gender of German nouns in Kivy python and I wanted to  have an unfocus event in the Text Input so only when the user unfocuses from the
'MDTextFieldRound' , the search method can be called which will give the list of all german nouns according to entered prefix in the MDTextField...
Here is the main python file:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextFieldRound
from mst import genderGetter
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem


class MenuScreen(Screen):
   pass


class GenderGameScreen(Screen):
   pass


class GenderScreen(Screen):
    words = list(genderGetter().keys())

    def get_len(self):
        return len(self.get_text())

    def search(self):
        self.get_text()

        self.create_list()

    def get_text(self):
        gen = self.ids.gender.text.lower().capitalize()
        return gen

    def create_list(self):
        for word in self.words:
            if self.get_text() in word[0:self.get_len()]:
                items = TwoLineListItem(text=word, secondary_text=genderGetter().get(word))
                self.ids.contain.add_widget(items)


class GenderText(MDTextFieldRound):
    pass


class TranslatorScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))


class GermanApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        screen = Builder.load_file('kv files/main.kv')
        return screen


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = GermanApp()
   app.run()
```

Here is the kivy file of gender.kv

```
<GenderScreen>:
id:genders
name:'gender'

ScrollView:
    size_hint:(.5,.8)
    MDList:
        id: contain
MDTextFieldRound:
    id: gender
    hint_text: "Enter the German noun"
    helper_text: "Correct one"
    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
    pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.45 , "center_y" : 0.9}
    icon_right_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
    size_hint_x : 0.8
    on_text:root.search()
```

I am still a noob in kivy so there can be many potential mistakes in code...
Please consider that..

Comment: have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410573/is-there-a-focus-lost-event-dispatcher-for-a-kivy-textinput

Comment: can you suggests some improvements in code